# How to load custom stylesheet with NSwag's UseSwaggerUi3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, nswag

I'm trying to customize the swagger UI with my own .css stylesheet.

I am using asp net core 2.1 and NSwag.AspNetCore 12.2.5.

I've searched around and found that in previous versions this would be done by embedding my custom stylesheet and then injecting it in my middleware configuration with something like:

```
app.UseSwagger(o =>
{
   o.InjectStylesheet("/css/custom.css");
});
```

In the latest version of NSwag this seems to have changed to:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CustomStylesheetUri = new Uri("/css/custom.css", UriKind.Relative);
});
```

But either I'm not making the stylesheet available, or my uri is not pointing at it correctly.

I don't fully understand how the web server serves up the swagger files (I assume they are loaded from the NSwag nuget package, but I don't see them in my build output folder), so I assume I am not making the stylesheet available correctly.

Doing the above, I see the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">` added to the swagger index.html, but chrome developer tools says the file cannot be found.

I have tried:
1. Adding my stylesheet to wwwroot.
2. Adding my stylesheet somewhere in the project and explicitly copying it to the output folder in my csproj.
3. Embedding my stylesheet in the build artifact.

I have `.UseStaticFiles()` in my middleware pipeline.

What am I missing? Does anyone have a working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Main Answer**

If it does not exist, create a `wwwroot` folder in your project and create subfolders such as `css`, `img`, `js` within the `wwwroot` folder so that you'll have something like this:

```
wwwroot\css
wwwroot\img
wwwroot\js
```

The `UseStaticFiles()` method looks for the `wwwroot` folder and makes it servable.

The next you need to make sure of is that your .csproj file for the project contains the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Which basically says that all subfolders and files under wwwroot are going to be published.

With that stuff set up, your `cfg.CustomStylesheetUri = new Uri("/css/custom.css", UriKind.Relative)` code should now work.

---

### **Alternate Option**

As another option, if you want to serve your css file from a different directory outside of wwwroot, then you will need to specify the `StaticFileOptions` parameter in the `UseStaticFiles()` method in order to serve your css.  Here's my working example but with [ReDoc](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc).

I'm using [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) which extends Swagger to generate and further customize my OpenAPI specification file.  (***ReDoc via NSwag uses `CustomStylesheetUri` insead of `InjectStylesheet` but I imagine it works the same way***).

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
            RequestPath = "/Content"
        });

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();
        app.UseReDoc(c => {
            c.Path = "/redoc";
            c.DocumentPath = "/swagger/v1/swagger.json";
            c.CustomStylesheetUri = new Uri("/Content/redoc-styles.css", UriKind.Relative); //added towards the end of the <head>
            c.CustomJavaScriptUri = new Uri("/Content/redoc-javascript.js", UriKind.Relative);  //added at the end of the <body>
        });
```

My above code references a folder that I created called **Content** in which I added **css** and **js** files.  My folder is at the root of the project: *MyAPIProject/Content/redoc-styles.css*

Along with this secondary example, an additional thing to make sure of is that your .csproj file contains the relevant entries (otherwise the folder and files won't be published):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\css\redoc-styles.css">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Content\js\redoc-javascript.js">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think my mistake was thinking that `dotnet build`/`dotnet run` would by default copy the wwwroot over, same as `dotnet publish` does, and this is not the case. So when debugging in an IDE my stylesheet was not where my application expected. I ended up putting my stylesheet inside wwwroot/swagger just for simplicity as thats the folder name swagger uses for its files, and then using just `new Uri("custom.css", UriKind.Relative)`.

Comment: Why is this injected into non swagger pages? Seems like a serious bug...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore). So your code will be like this

My example. Please make sure your middleware are in correct order

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Awesome CMS Core API V1");
    c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css"); //css in your wwwrootfolder 
});


// Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
  {
    Version = "v1",
    Title = "Awesome CMS Core API V1",
    Contact = new Contact { Name = "Tony Hudson", Email = "", Url = "https://github.com/ngohungphuc" }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will fall back to that if I can't figure out how to do it with NSwag, but NSwag does seem to support this so I will first try to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Sample.NETCore20/Startup.cs
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Sample.NETCore21/Startup.cs
Take a look at these

Comment: These is a issue about this https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1137