# How to add bold letter in swagger description in .NET Core

Tags: c#, swagger

How to add bold letter in swagger description in .NET Core?

I have tried but nothing works. I don't know if this is possible. The version used is 5.0.0.

I am going into the documentation that is added with 3 `///`

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Esta es una prueba <strong>NEGRITA 1</strong>, __Negrita 2__, **Negrita 3**, _Negrita 4_, *Negrita 5*, <remarks>Negrita 6</remarks>, 
/// <b>Negrita 7</b>, <code>otro</code>, ## titulo, # titulo 2
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>`
```

[image]

Comment: I have never seen it in `summary` as it should be a very short one liner of your operation. If you try it in `description` tag you should be able to follow [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/help/) syntax

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load custom stylesheet with NSwag's UseSwaggerUi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996665/how-to-load-custom-stylesheet-with-nswags-useswaggerui3)

Comment: @Jhilton you should post your comment as an answer (because it's the correct answer).

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen it working in the `summary` tag as this should be a very short one-liner of what your operation does, hence all of it should be important.

If you are trying to add a more complex text of what the operation does, you should try using the `description` tag instead.

For most Swagger Viewers the Open API `description` allows [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/help/) syntax
For editing the attribute use the `remarks` tag in the comments

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Tests bold formatting in Swagger UI
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This should appear in **bold text** :)
/// </remarks>
```